# Merge [numerology] into [numbers]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There are currently 11 questions tagged with [numerology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerology), which, according to Wiktionary, means:

> The study of the purported mystical relationship between numbers (or the letters of words, represented by numbers) and the character or action of physical objects and living things.

It looks as though everyone using this tag is under the mistaken impression that it refers to the more mundane mathematical properties of numbers, so I suggest that it be merged into [numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numbers).

Comment: Can I propose the other way around? Because I really love that Wiktionary meaning: _"The study of the purported mystical relationship between numbers (or the letters of words, represented by numbers) and the character or action of physical objects and living things."_

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wikipedia has a more clear description:

> Numerology is any belief in the divine or mystical relationship between a number and one or more coinciding events. It is also the study of the numerical value of the letters in words, names and ideas. It is often associated with the paranormal, alongside astrology and similar divinatory arts.

So basically it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. Instead of merging the tags, I suggest retagging the questions instead and let the [numerology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerology) tag get removed.

Comment: That was what I had in mind - wasn't aware of any distinction between a merge and a retag.

Comment: @jsheeran Actually I assumed that both tags keep existing after a merge, but apparently [that depends on whether a synonym exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work). Either way, tag merges can only be done by moderators, and since there are only 11 questions we can do it ourselves easily.

Comment: Looks like it's done now